# Is it always true if two random variables are jointly Gaussian, then they must be individually Gaussian as well?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If I have two random variables, $X$ and $Y$, such that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is jointly Gaussian, is it ALWAYS true that $f_{X}(x)$ and $f_{Y}(y)$ are Gaussian as well?

If $f_{X,Y}(x,y) \sim N(\mu_{XY}, \sigma_{XY}^{2})$ with correlation $\rho$, then $f_{X}(x) \sim N(\mu_{X}, \sigma_{X}^{2})$ and $f_{Y}(y) \sim N(\mu_{y}, \sigma_{y}^{2})$.

Is there an exception?

Comment: For, by definition, a random vector $Z$ is Gaussian _signifies_ that for whatever linear transformation $L,$ the image vector $L(Z)$ is also Gaussian (when $L$ is a _linear form_, we must have $L(Z)$ a normal random variable).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is always true. If $X$ and $Y$ are jointly Gaussian with mean $\mu = (\mu_x, \mu_y)$ and 
covariance matrix $\Sigma$, then $X$ is Gaussian with mean $\mu$ and variance $\Sigma_{1,1}$.  Just integrate out the other variable: 
$$f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)\; dy $$

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering, because it is possible for individual Gaussian distributions to not be jointly Gaussian, whether the converse might be true as well.